# i am trying to pass values to an array in another class

Tags: c#

i am trying to pass values to an array in another class
this is an example of what i am trying to do in detail:

```
public class CustomString
{

private string[] StringToAppend;


    public string[] StringToAppend1
    {
        get
        {
            return StringToAppend;
        }

        set
        {
            StringToAppend = value;
        }

       }

  public Class Form1:Form

 {

  CustomString strng1 = new CustomString();

  strng1.StringToAppend1 = {"sssf","vfdr";} //Fails to compile Here
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
strng1.StringToAppend1 = {"sssf","vfdr";} //Fails to compile Here
```

That is the incorrect syntax for initialising a string array

```
strng1.StringToAppend1 = new[]{"sssf","vfdr"} ;
```

Above is the correct syntax.